# Twitter API to fetch users with most number of followers

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am looking for a twitter API to fetch top 10 users with most followers. Does any such API exist?

Comment: I am not getting any such API. That's why I have posted here.

Comment: Why would you need API for something like that? Just google the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API does not have this. The API is documented here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs

Comment: thanks for letting me know this. Is these any way we can achieve this?